# Does HDMI connected LCD monitor produce sound from my computer?

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, lcd, tv

I Have a question about using an HDMI-connected LCD TV.

When I use 'extend' to extend my desktop to my TV, how do I get the audio to (appropriately) play from the TV?  For example, when I put a movie in the computer, will the audio be played from the TV automatically when the movie is displayed on the TV? If not, when will the audio be played from my TV and not my PC's speakers?  How do I output sound on the TV when the associated video content is being displayed there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screen configuration doesn’t matter. Instead, you need to check your audio output configuration on whether the HDMI output is enabled and selected as the default device.

Be aware that some older PC HDMI ports are not equipped to transmit audio.

Comment: i will clearify my question: when connecting lcd via HDMI to a PC, when would the audio be played from the tv, and when from pc?

Comment: It plays from the TV when HDMI audio is selected as default in your operating system’s sound settings(, or when a program explicitly selects to output on HDMI). Sound output is not concerned with screen configuration, let alone window positions.